# String выход за пределы

Tags: java, строки

```java
String str = "01234";
        System.out.println(str.charAt(4));
        if(str.charAt(5) != null) {      //Каким образом выполнить проверку на существование элемента
            System.out.println(str.charAt(5));
        }
```

Вопрос: Как создать проверку на выход за пределы длины строки?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (str.length() > 5)
    System.out.println(str.charAt(5));
```

Comment: @НазарСтинянский ничего страшного, у всех бывает. Можете и удалить.

Comment: Пусть всегда будет

Answer (score 1):

Если мы заранее не знаем к какому символу строки по индексу будем обращаться - как вариант можно использовать механизм обработки исключений Java, например:

```
    public class Example{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String str = "01234";
            try{
                System.out.println(str.charAt(6));  
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Warning! We have an accident! \n" + e);
            }       
        } 
    }
```

Здесь мы обращаемся к символу строки под индексом 6, которого нет. Вылетит исключение, мы его перехватим и обработаем с пояснением.

Comment: Лучший ответ, я считаю. Только ещё добавить фразу о том, что об accident-е будут доложено куда надо.